# What format do you use in Google BigQuery to specify a table.column when getting a "column name is ambiguous" error?

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have tried every combination I can think of in Bigquery, but when I get this error, I am trying to follow standard SQL procedures in putting Table_name.column but this format is not working.

I want to select the "Event_ID" field but that field is in two different tables I am using. It should be the same so I don't really care which one it pulls.

I've tried these formats, moving parentheses and periods around:

'table_name.event_id'
`table_name.event_id`
`table_name`event_id

The table name I am working with is very long, which may complicate things. Here is a stripped down version:

`highestlevelfoldername_datasetname.tablename` --I have tried `highestlevelfoldername_datasetname.tablename.event_id` -- and that is not working

I've googled around and also do not see the correct formatting.

[image: Here is the image of the error message]

Comment: please share the full query that it's giving you an error

Comment: Lookup aliases and joins in sql

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add alias to your table and then use it to identify the field to select

For example,

```
select a.event_id
from `project.dataset.table1` a
...
```

Comment: I can't edit existing tables but can create new tables, would this still work?

Comment: where you see you need to edit existing tables? aliases are to be added in select statements

Comment: the table alias worked after adding it in the from statement, I adjusted the select statements and it looks good to go. never used it before and great help - thanks!